# issues with getline() and input stream

Tags: c++, stream, cin, getline

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char s[20];
    char ch;
    
    std::cin.getline(s,10);
    std::cout<<"x"<<s<<"x"<<"\n";
    
    std::cin>>ch;
    std::cout<<"x"<<ch<<"x";
    
    std::cin>>ch;
    std::cout<<"x"<<ch<<"x";
    
    std::cin>>ch;
    std::cout<<"x"<<ch<<"x";
}
```

**Output-1**

```
bonaparte    // I entered these 9 characters as input
xbonapartex
a            //  input
xax
b            // input
xbx
c            // input
xcx
```

**Output-2**

```
bonaparte2    // I entered these 10 characters as input
xbonapartex
x x
x x
x x
```

I just entered one extra letter means total 10 char through keyboard `bonaparte2` compared to 1st output.

According to me getline is going to extract 9 characters and add '\0' and store in string `s`. So stream remains with characters `2` and `\n`. so first `cin>>ch` should take `2` and print `x2x`.

Now 2nd `cin>>ch` should ignores `\n` as it is leading whitespace character but none of this is happening.  Program is not asking from input from keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Output-2, `std::cin.getline(s,10);` fails (because it can't read a complete line). It then sets the stream in a failed state and all subsequent extractions will also fail (unless you [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the stream).

```
if(not std::cin.getline(s, 10)) { // an empty string is considered ok
    if(std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "end of file / input closed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if(std::cin.bad()) {
        std::cout << "a non-recoverable error has occurred\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // failbit
    std::cout << "Too long string entered\n";
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

If you don't want the stream to be set in a failed state when a newline is not found within the first 9 characters read, you can use the below instead. Note that it may still set `eofbit` or `failbit` for reasons illustrated below:

```
if(not std::cin.get(s, 10)) {   // an empty string sets failbit
    if(std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "end of file / input closed\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if(std::cin.bad()) {
        std::cout << "a non-recoverable error has occurred\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // failbit
    std::cout << "No string entered\n";
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: first of all Thanks and  this not happens with cin.get() right ?

Comment: @ForrestGump You're welcome. I added info about that.

Answer (score 2):

In `std::cin.getline(s,10);`, as the input is bigger than `stream_size` provided, `istream::getline` sets the stream into a fail state, and that prevents further input.

It can easily be fixed with `std::cin.clear()`. Using `std::string` to store the input and let it handle the length will also be an alternative.

Related :

- [cin.getline( ) with larger size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053957/cin-getline-with-larger-size)
- [Why would we call cin.clear() and cin.ignore() after reading input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131647/why-would-we-call-cin-clear-and-cin-ignore-after-reading-input)

Comment: but this not happens with `cin.get()` right ?